# What happened to "last seen" in Profile?

Tags: support, users, user-interface

Looking at members' Profiles, I no longer see the notice as to when the individual was last heard from. Has it been deleted?

Comment: It should still be there under the profile tab. I can see yours under https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55119/user55119?tab=profile

Comment: I'm looking at yours and I don't see it, at least where it used to be located.

Comment: @BuckThorn might be a mod feature. \ This is not a feature request though and is probably better asked on main meta. I'm too booked to look myself, but I guess such a change will be documented somewhere. I see this as a privacy feature though.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン That was my next guess but wanted to make sure it wasn't an oversight first. I haven't kept up with news on the site layout front. I'll go snoop around to see what is up.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Yes looks like it's gone: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23148/last-seen-time-appears-on-google-and-se-profile-pages-and-should-be-removed See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive I haven't kept up with this. I can't provide a good answer at this time.

Comment: @Buck Cool, thanks. I only checked on a site I don't moderate, there I couldn't see it either. For a mod the information might be necessary, for a normal user I don't really see the point to be honest. This is not social media and you can still see the last action on the activity tab. So you'll get an idea...

Answer (score 8):

Stack Overflow-the-company made some changes to user profiles in early August 2021, which, let's say, were not taken very positively: [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive)

The "last seen" part of your profile is now only visible to you and the moderators on each site. So, unless you are a moderator, you cannot see anybody else's "last seen".

[In a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive#comment1228272_368289), animuson (SO staff) wrote that

> We've actually had quite a few complaints in the past that a "Last seen" indicator public visible is a creepy and intrusive thing to have on a user profile.

The top response to that linked post is basically a complaint about this, and contains links to other answers arguing for and against the change, if that's of interest to you. (Personally, I don't really have a strong opinion on it either way, although if privacy is a concern, then it certainly makes sense to at least put it behind a flag.) But anyway, that's what happened to it.